# understanding match in python

Tags: python, regex, match

I have two variables storing path in python

```
var1 = u'Manish/testfolder/.*txt'
var2 = u'Manish/testfolder/test.txt.abc'
```

if I type 
`re.match(var1 , var2 )`

it yeilds true can someone explain how is it evaluating to true and what I shall I do so that it returns false.

Comment: I havn't used it but seeing that its regex compare then the two statements are the same. ".*" matches all chars.

Comment: I guess you expect it to return false as your string doesn't end with `.txt`? You are missing the end of string anchor `$` in this case. You could also use `re.fullmatch` if you are using python 3.

Comment: I guess you're asking that because you expected it was not going to match because var2 ends with .txt.abc instead of only txt?

If so, it's because you're not specifying the end of string special char $

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is included inside var2.

If you explicit set an end for your regex, it's not matching anymore:

```
var1 = u'Manish/testfolder/.*txt$'
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)  `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string.